# Extract integer/number from buffer content

Tags: c++, string, client-server, buffer

It is server side code which accepting data from the client and displaying.
Content of buffer after run code is

clientID=10:hi

but i want to extract only clientID no (that is 10) from total buffer content.
client id can be range from 0-1000 and message send by client also non fixed size.

I am trying like this but it become static.

```
cout<<buffer;
std::string str=buffer;
std::string str1=str.substr(8,9);
cout<<str1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Split string once at the `'='`, then split the string `"10:hi"` at the `':'`, then use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the string to a number.

For the splitting, see e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).